# Forcing print page break after X records using CGridView

Tags: yii

I use CGridView to render a result (invoice rows) from a db query. This is done inside a `<div>` on html page that is later converted to a PDF using `wkhtmltopdf` and printed. The problem is that today I have no support for page break so if number of invoice rows are greater than 10 the remaining rows are not visible. I can't let the div flow since I have an invoice footer with an absolute position that can't move.

Is there a way to force a page break and continue rendering rows on a separate page?

Below is part of the CGridView code used.

```php
<...plenty of html---->
<div class="invoiceRow">
<?php

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dpRows,
    'cssFile' => Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/css/invoice.css',
    'summaryText' => '',
    'enablePagination' => false,
    'columns' => array(
        'number',
        'name',
        'description',
        'amount',
        array (
            'name'=>'value',
            'header' => 'netprice',
            'value' => 'number_format($data->value,2,","," ")'
        ),
    ));
?>
</div>
<---more html ----->
```

Comment: what do you meaning at `force a page break`? insert `<br />` tag every ten records?

Comment: Generating a PDF manually instead of relying on HTML would give you a lot more control over the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If wkhtml is able to parse css (it seems so) you could try:

```
<div style="page-break-after:always">
    //X invoices here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($model))
{
if($model->content_type==1)
{
    $sentences = explode ('<div style="page-break-after: always;"><span style="display:none">&nbsp;</span></div>',$model->content);
    ?>
    <div id="datashow">
        <?php
        echo $sentences[0];
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    $dummy=array();
    $kcnt=preg_match_all('/page-break-after: always/', $model->content,$dummy);
    // echo $model->content;
}



<script>
    $("#pagebreakdiv").find(":button").click(function () {
        var datashow=$('#datashow');
        var a=this.value;
        var bid='<?php echo $bid; ?>';
        var id='<?php echo $id; ?>';
        var pdata = {};
        pdata["bitt"] = a;
        pdata["bid"] = bid;
        pdata["id"] = id;
        $.ajax(
            {
                url : "<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/UserSimple/Contentpagebreak",
                type: "POST",
                data : pdata,
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    datashow.html(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {

                }
            });
    });
</script>
```